# strreplace for space?

Tags: php, regex

i have for example:

```
$one = 'aaa bbb ccc sss ddd www';
$two = '### !!!';
$three = '111 222 333 444';
```

i would like make in php function that show me max 3 words of each string:

```
echo functioncut($one) = aaa bbb ccc
echo functioncut($two) = ### !!!
echo functioncut($three) == 111 222 333
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you could get an array of words:

```
$allwords = explode(' ', $one);
```

wich is easy to use to get the first three elements using [array_chunk](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($allwords, 3);
$firstthreewords = $chunks[0];
```

and at least, use [implode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get back one string:

```
$string = implode(' ', $firstthreewords);
```

wrapping this into a single function would give us:

```
function functioncut($v){
  $allwords = explode(' ', $v);
  $chunks = array_chunk($allwords, 3);
  return implode(' ', $chunks[0]);
}
```

or (short&easy, but kind of unreadable):

```
function functioncut($v){
  return implode(' ',array_shift(array_chunk(explode(' ', $v), 3)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any PHP function that does this.. But you could try this:

```
function wordSplit( $string, $number ) {
    return implode( ' ', array_slice( explode( ' ', $string ), 0, $number ) );
}

echo wordSplit( 'aaa bbb ccc sss ddd www', 3 ); // aaa bbb ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explode to split the string by space, then echo just the first 3 in the array...

```
$one = 'aaa bbb ccc sss ddd www';
$r1 = explode(' ',$one);
echo $r1[0].' '.$r1[1].' '.$r1[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regexp — you can use preg_replace() with this expression:

```
echo preg_replace( '~^(([\S]*[\s]?){3}).*~', '$1', $one );
```

Answer (score -1):

`split()` function will help you for details click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

Comment: note that split() is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3. you really shouldn't recommend using this.

Comment: "This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."